# Installer VS 2008

Tags: runtime, windows-installer, libraries

My application uses some dll which have been developed using MFC VS 2005. My current application is built using VS 2008 VC++dot net. How can i get the installer to include the Visual c++ runtime libraries???

Comment: What are you using to create the installer?

Comment: I created a setup deployment project to create installer in VS 2008.

Answer (score 0):

In a Visual Studio setup project you can add the Visual C++ Redistributables as prerequisites:

- right-click your setup project in Solution Explorer
- click Prerequisites button
- select the prerequisites you want to include